# How to implement Single Sign-On on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am a new enterprise iOS developer. We are developing an app that is managing our enterprise apps(somehow like a app store&MDM).

**I stacked by a issue :**

I want to implement Single Sign-On for our enterprise Apps (Not with the same Developer ID), which means if the app-store App is signed in, the other apps(involved in our enterprise app platform) do not need users to enter ID & PassWord again.

I have searched for the same and I got some information which mentioned sharing keychain and iOS Kerberos SSO. But sharing the keychain is not available for apps developed by different Developers and I cannot find some detailed resource about Kerberos for iOS SSO.

Therefore, what I need is:

- Is the Kerberos SSO OK for my case?
- I want some detailed tutorial or articles through which I can learn How to make a SSO server and how to configure my iOS application?

Comment: You cannot share any keychain data with other apps which doesnt belong to same developer ID

Comment: Yes, that is what I am struggling with

Comment: Well as @nanjunda told you, you'll keep on struggling then, because it's not possible

Comment: What about creating a general app, which allows to log in, and redirecting users to that app(webpage) if they want to log in..? You can't share keychain and anything other than that is insecure with jailbreak (and sometimes even without jailbreak).

Comment: @YueKong did you implemented this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently iOS 8 includes a certificate-support that allows the use of certificate-based single sign-on for users to authenticate to enterprise apps.

> **[Accounts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024)**
>
> The Accounts framework (Accounts.framework)
>   provides a single sign-on model for certain user accounts. Single
>   sign-on improves the user experience by eliminating the need to prompt
>   the user separately for multiple accounts. It also simplifies the
>   development model for you by managing the account authorization
>   process for your app. You use this framework in conjunction with the
>   Social framework.

So you should take a look in [Accounts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024)

Comment: Thank you Niko, that's helpful

Comment: @Niko Hi, as you said single sign-on model for certain user accounts. Can u have a doc where apple has mention that it will only work with certain account. because @property(readonly, nonatomic) NSString *identifier; is accepting a string and not enum.. I need a doc so I can include in my R&D that its not possible with other acocunts