# how to integrate SAML with iOS Native App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, saml

How can I use native code for SAML inegration in iOS app? I have a `Objective-C` App for `iOS > iOS7`. Is there a way to invoke SAML authentication using native code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Single Sign-On on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343728/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-on-ios)